# partition function for quick sort not working

Tags: arrays, c, function, quicksort, partition

I'm trying to write in c the partition function used for quicksort whose parameters are the array, length of array n and pivot index.

My code so far:

```
        void swap(int *a, int *b){
            int temp = *a;
            *a = *b; 
            *b = temp;
        }
```

```
    int rearrange(int* array, int n, int pivot_index){  //rearrange function 
        int pivot = array[pivot_index];
        int i = n-(n)-1;
        int j = array[0];
        swap(array[pivot_index],array[0]);
        for (j=0; j<n; j++);
            if (array[j] < array[pivot_index]){
                i++;
                ;swap(array[i], array[j]);
        swap(array[i+1], array[pivot_index]);
        return i+1;
        }

    }
```

However, it doesn't pass the test cases.
Thank you.

Test case it has to pass:

```
        int main(void) {
            int a[] = {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0};
            rearrange(a,6,2);

            int correct_ans[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1};
            for (int i=0;i<6;i++) {
            if (a[i]!=correct_ans[i]) {
                printf("Rearrange error, incorrect order\n");
                return false;
            }
          }

              printf("AC\n");

           return 0;
        }
```

Comment: If your program doesn't work the thing to do is to debug it. Run your program in a debugger and/or add debug print statements to trace the execution of your program. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Note the signature of `void swap(int *a, int *b)`. What are you passing in `swap(array[i], array[j])`, two `int`s or two `int *`?

Comment: This line `for (j=0; j<n; j++);` looks like it shouldn't have a semicolon, so what you probably think is the loop body is only executed once. Your code is not properly formatted/indented, which makes it harder for yourself to find errors.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
if (array[j] < array[pivot_index]){
```

instead it should be

```
if (array[j] < pivot){
```

You moved the pivot value all the way to the front with your initial swap, so it's not at `pivot_index` anymore.